# Launching html file in c++

Tags: c++, winapi, launching

I am trying to open a local html document using Shell Execute(). But, what i need is, Suppose if that particular document is already opened and if ShellExecute is triggered again, then that particular file should not be opened again instead bring the already opened file into foreground. Can you please suggest how can i do this?

```
void main()
{  
  ShellExecute(NULL, "open", "C:\\prograomgiles\\help.html",
              NULL, NULL, SW_SHOWNORMAL);
 }
```

Comment: I think you need to get the handler of the opened application, and for each time you need to open the document checks if the handler is still exists(alive) just tell OS to either notify/switch to exists application, it could be done(in easier manner) via a 3rd. party application that take cares about it

Answer (score 1):

It's nearly impossible, because it depends on which program processes the `html` files and how does it work. Suppose, that my OS opens `html` files by printing them directly on a printer. How would you bring opened file into foreground?

If you want to display HTML content in the way specified by you, write your own browser (It's quite easy, you can - for example - [embed IE in C#.NET application](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/windowsdesktop/Building-a-web-browser-in-C-8f992c88)) and run it instead of default system browser. You would have then full control on how your files are displayed.

Answer (score 1):

Many web browsers respond to DDE messages, particularly the `WWW_OpenURL` message.  Not sure about other browsers, but IE also responds to `WWW_GetWindowInfo` and `WWW_Activate` messages, which you could use to enumerate open windows and their URLs, and then activate a particular window.